# Trouble with Dynamic Imports in React Native TypeScript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm encountering an issue with dynamic imports in a React Native app using TypeScript. I'm attempting to dynamically import JSON files based on a `reference` prop in one of my components, but I'm facing an error that I can't resolve.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";

type Props = {
  reference: string;
};

const Block = ({ reference }: Props) => {
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const module = await import(`../../../assets/data/topics/${reference}`);
        setUnit(module);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error loading data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [reference]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {unit.map((block: any) => (
        <View key={block.blockId} style={styles.blockBox}>
          <Text style={styles.boxText}>{block.blockName}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Block;
```

The `reference` prop is just a string for the end of the path `units/top-1-sec-1-unit-1.json`.

The error I'm seeing is:

**Invalid call at line 16: import(`../../../assets/data/topics/${reference}`)**

I've checked the path, and it seems correct. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue? I'd appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you!